# How are CCA's (Cold Cranking Amps) measured, specifically with regard to the load resistance?

Tags: power, batteries, amperage, power-engineering

I'm not interested in the "cold" part of CCA's. Here is my understanding:

1. The electrical system draws (by far) the most power during the actual start-up of the engine.
2. The idea (more or less) is to disconnect the battery from the car.  Then hook it up to a "load" that effectively replicates the power draw an engine start-up would require, and see if the battery can hold 12 volts during a large power draw from the load.
3. It seems a reasonably common CCA rating is 500 Amps.

The fly in the ointment so to speak is that I'm not sure if the 500 Amp draw is referring to the pre or post ignition coil part of the electrical system.
If it is pre-ignition coil, that would mean that:

V=I x R

12 = 500 x R

R = 24 mili Ohms

24 mili Ohms seems like a super bizarre number.  I've never even seen anything under a single ohm before (not to say it doesn't exist).
Not to mention if this is really the case lets think about power.

P = I x V

P = 500 x 12

P = 6kW

Somehow I don't see any 24 mili Ohm resistors being able to handle 6kW of power.  Maybe they put a  incredible number of them in parallel to divi it up?

Okay so maybe its post ignition coil. I think the secondary side of an ignition coil might produce 30kV.

V = I x R

30k = 500 x R

R = 60 ohms

P = I x V

P = 500 x 30 k

P = 15MW

holy smokes that is a lot of power.  My understanding is that power remains equal going through the ignition coil transformation (if anything you lose power).  Therefore taking that power back to the pre-ignition coil side of things:

P = I x V

15MW = I x 12

I = 1.25 M Amp

That ain't it.

---

So I'm at a bit of a loss here.  What is the load used during a CCA test?  and what part of the electrical system is actually using 500 Amps?

Comment: The 500 or so amps are used by the starter motor to rotate it, not by the ignition coil. Also energy does not come out of nowhere. If an ignition coil outputs 1W, there must be 1W going into it, assuming it is ideal and there is no losses.

Comment: it takes time to heat a resistor to the point where it begins to melt ... turn off the current before that happens

Comment: Might help to think of that 6 kW (or 3.6kW as explained below) as 8 horsepower (or 5). That seems reasonable to turn over a large car engine when it's cold and the oil is at its stickiest.

Comment: CCA is all for the 12V starter motor. It has little or nothing to do with the ignition coil(s). Yes obviously the ignition coils need power too, but 99% of that 500A (or whatever) goes to the starter motor.

Comment: You use 0.024 ohm things every day.  Ever plug into a wall socket? The wiring back to your panel is probably 0.024 ohms.  Both legs!  USB cable, each wire is probably that.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-902a-how-to-measure-cca) article explains it.

According to the article, there are 3 different standards:

- Fully charge battery according
  to SAE J537 and cool to -18°C (0°F) for 24 hours. While at subfreezing temperature, apply a discharge current equal to the specified CCA. (500 CCA battery discharges at 500A.) To pass, the voltage must stay above 7.2V (1.2V/cell) for 30 seconds.
- Fully charge battery according
  to SAE J537 and cool to -18°C (0°F) for 24 hours. While at subfreezing temperature, apply
  a discharge current equal to the specified CCA. (500 CCA battery discharges at 500A.) To pass, the voltage must stay above 8.4V for 60 seconds.
- Fully charge battery according
  to SAE J537 and cool to -18°C (0°F) for 24 hours. While at subfreezing temperature, apply a discharge current equal to the specified CCA. (500 CCA battery discharges at 500A.) To pass, the voltage must stay above 9V for 30s and 6V for 150s.

To test against these standards, a constant current load is used, not a simple resistor.

Moving on to your power calculations, there are a lot of mistakes and misconceptions there.

- **The battery is not a fixed voltage source.** The voltage will droop in various ways during cranking. There will be an instantaneous drop in voltage, which is similar to a series resistor with your battery, and there will also be a more gradual decrease in voltage as the battery discharges. According to the 1st standard, the voltage can drop as low as 7.2V and it's still a pass. That puts the minimum wattage at 3.6KW.
- **Almost 100% of the power is going to the starter motor** The ignition coil isn't drawing a significant amount.
- **24mOhm, aka 0.024 ohms is actually a reasonable ESR for a car battery.** If it was even 1ohm, the absolute maximum current the battery could put out would be about 13A. And that's with no load, just a dead short across the terminals.
- **The ignition coil (a transformer) steps up the voltage, but the secondary current decreases proportionally.** As you said, the power is constant (minus losses). If you use a transformer to step 120V up to 240V, the voltage is doubled, but the current capability is halved.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.  My confusion was I thought in order to test 600 Amps from a 12 volt battery you would have to attach an appropriate load which would be 20mOhms.  I found this unlikely to be how they actually test it.  Thanks again for the wisdom and the attached article

Answer (score 0):

The Cold Cranking Amp rating is a measure of the current that the battery can deliver under specified test conditions.  The great majority of the current will be used by the starter motor.